# Minimum turning radius (or maximum banking angle) of a commercial airplane

Tags: aerodynamics, air-traffic-control, general-aviation, maneuver, maneuverability

The context of the work: in an ATC model, we currently have a graph model to set the routes for different aircraft. We want to improve its precision by generating more nodes for each route and in order for these nodes to be feasible (i.e., reachable by the aircraft) you do that embedding the Dynamics of the vehicle in the generation of nodes.

Bottom line, I need some **"citable" source** where I can find the values for the minimum turning radius of an airplane. Since it is preferrable to be conservative than to implement something that cannot be done, I am looking for "large" commercial aircraft as I understand they will set an upper bound. That said, it is a research work so it doesn't need to be "the largest aircraft that ever cruised over the airspace", just some reasonably big airplane that is commonly used: Boeing 747, Airbus A380,etc..

Note: only Civilian flights are considered, therefore military crafts are not relevant here

Comment: Keep in mind this turn radius depends on airspeed, which in turn depends on altitude (that's why enroute holds are so dang big)

Comment: Depends - do you want them to pull several G's to make a small radius or do you want to avoid having a few hundred complaining passengers?

Comment: Don't have a source to cite, but 30 degrees of bank is the max anybody is going to use for ATC purposes.  Plug that in with your assumed True Air Speed, and you can get a turn radius (which assumes still air).  Allow for wind effects as well, since 100 knots tailwind/crosswind will make for a larger effective turn radius than just the TAS alone. There is probably someplace in the AIM or an ATC regulation that mentions the 30 degrees value, although offhand I don't know where -- sorry about that.

Comment: If you look for emergency procedures, see [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/what-is-the-maximum-safe-bank-angle-of-a-747) and [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8012/what-does-it-take-to-turn-a-747-around-180-degrees) question.